# Remember my "sort by" setting when browsing favorite site feeds

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Opening the menu and selecting an item from the "Favorite Sites" menu allows us to see a feed for a specific site. In the top right corner of this page is a drop-down which allows us to select the "sort order" for the posts. The default is "Active" with other options like "Newest", "Hot", etc.

The problem is that when I select "Newest" or any other option. This preference is not remembered when I change between a different "Favorite Site".

So I am requesting that the selection is persisted when changing between site feeds. I have no preference whether this is implemented per site (to allow a different default for each site) or just one single preferred default that works on all sites (last option selected). I just want it to remember that I have selected "Newest" when I am flicking though the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.0.12 your last used sort value is saved and chosen by default when you visit another site.